# How to implement code if the textbox is empty error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

There is this problem I have been having when it comes to implementing a method if both text boxes were empty. Whenever I do `IsNullOrEmpty` or textbox == 0, I get an exemption on my text boxes.

Is there any way I can approach this in a simpler way?

```
 public int number 1;
 public int number 2;
 public int answer 3;

 private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {  
       //text box
       number1 = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
       number2 = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

        //if number1 and number2 are less than 1
        if (number1 < 1 || number2 < 1 || number1 > 100 || number2 > 100)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("INVALID INPUT");
            TextBox1.Text = " ";
            TextBox2.Text = " ";
        }
        // if both text boxes are empty 
        // send error message
        // end if statement
        else
        {
            // operation
            answer = number1 + number2;
            //
            // when clicked
            answerText.Text = answer.ToString();
        }
}
```

Comment: The code shown does not include any of the parts of `IsNullOr empty or textbox == 0`. Please provide a [mcve]. Please also explain clearly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0).

```
bool number1b = int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out number1)
bool number2b = int.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out number2);

if (number1b && number2b)
{
    if (number1 < 1 || number2 < 1 || number1 > 100 || number2 > 100)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Integer inputs can not be outside of 1-100.");
    }
    else
    {
        answer = number1 + number2;
        answerText.Text = answer.ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Inputs could not be converted to an integer.");
}
```